# PDF Control for WPF - Sticky Notes, highliting, user defined stamp text

Tags: wpf, pdf, controls, highlighting, stamp

I need an PDF Control for WPF which is able to allow such editing:

- Sticky Notes
- highlighting (text, lines, etc)
- user defined stampt text

If someone know such a control please let me know. Of course should be a commercial product.
Thank you!
Tom